# how parsing Firebase FDatasnapshot json data in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase

I'm having issue getting data from Firebase.

schema is

```
{
    title: "dog",
    images: {
        main: "dog.png",
        others: {
            0: "1.png",
            1: "2.png",
            2: "3.png"
        }
    }
}
```

how can i parse FDataSnapshot to swift model??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase is a NoSQL JSON database and has no schema and no tables. Data is  stored with a 'tree' structure with nodes; parents and children.

You don't need to parse Firebase JSON data to access it, you can access it directly.

FDataSnapshots contain a .key, which is it's parent key in Firebase and .value. .Value may contain one node, or multiple nodes. The Value will have key:value pairs representing the data within the snapshot

So for your example you will have a Firebase structure like this

```
dogs
  dog_id_0
    title: "dog"
    type: "Alaskan Malamute"
    images:
        main: "dog.png"
        others:
            0: "1.png"
            1: "2.png"
  dog_id_1
    title: "another dog"
    type: "Boxer"
    images:
        main: "another_dog.png"
        others:
            0: "3.png"
            1: "4.png"
```

So, say you want to read in each dog_id_x node one at a time and print some values.

```
var ref = Firebase(url:"https://your-app.firebaseio.com/dogs")

ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    println(snapshot.value.objectForKey("title"))
    println(snapshot.value.objectForKey("type"))
})
```

This will output

```
dog
Alaskan Malamute
another dog
Boxer
```

The dog_id_0 and dog_id_1 are node names created with the Firebase childByAutoId.

You could just as easily create a Dog class, and pass it the FDataSnapshot which will populate the class from the data within the snapshot.

Comment: Thank you for answer me. then how can i get array in the json??? i wonder getting "others" data with "main" to class or variable.

Comment: I mean parse from "images" key value to class or variables~!

Comment: The 'others' array is read like any other key:value pair. When you get .objectForTitle("others") the value will be the array. However, you may want to set up your structure differently as the use of array's are very situational and there are usually better ways to store your data that provides more flexibility. Array's can be a challenge so I generally avoid them.

Comment: What if I want to get data of dog_id_0 only using .ChildChanged ?

Comment: If you are only interested in dog_id_0, there are a number of options, here's two: 1) Add an observer specifically to that node. var ref = Firebase(url:"https://your-app.firebaseio.com/dogs/dog_id_0") with a .ChildChanged 2) Filter in code - if the snapshot.key = dog_id_0, ignore it.

Comment: @Jay I've been looking for help regarding a similar issue. It would mean a lot if you could you take a look at my question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494174/firebase-json-deserialization-swift thanks

Answer (score 2):

**February 2017 Update, Swift 3 Xcode 8**

Since a lot of things with Swift3 and Firebase have changed by the time this question was asked I will provide an updated way to parse Firebase data:

```
    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

    //I am registering to listen to a specific answer to appear
    self.ref.child("queryResponse").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        //in my case the answer is of type array so I can cast it like this, should also work with NSDictionary or NSNumber
        if let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSArray{
            //then I iterate over the values
            for snapDict in snapshotValue{
                //and I cast the objects to swift Dictionaries
                let dict = snapDict as! Dictionary<String, Any>
            }
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to play with this:

```
func makeItems(from snapshot: DataSnapshot) -> [SimpleItem] {
        var items = [SimpleItem]()
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshots {
                if let postDictionary = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    let item = SimpleItem(parentKey: snap.key, dictionary: postDictionary)
                    items.append(item)
                }
            }
        }
    return items
}
```

---

```
func loadItems() {
    firebaseService.databaseReference
        .child("items")
        .queryOrdered(byChild: "date")
        .queryLimited(toLast: 5)
        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            let items = self.makeItems(from: snapshot)
            print(" \(items)")
    }
}
```

---

```
class SimpleItem {
    var parentKey: String?

    var id: String?
    var description: String?

    init(parentKey: String, dictionary: [String : AnyObject]) {
        self.parentKey = parentKey

        id = dictionary["id"] as? String
        description = dictionary["description"] as? String
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could parse it maually with `Dictionary` or you can use my [library](https://github.com/Appyx/SnapshotParser).

Example code for your case:

```
func main(){
    let root=SnapshotParser().parse(snap: Snapshot, type: Root.self)
}

class Root: ParsableObject {
    var title:String?=nil
    var images:Images?=nil

    required init(){}

    func bindProperties(binder: SnapshotParser.Binder) {
        binder.bindField(name: "title", field: &title)
        binder.bindObject(name: "images", field: &images)
    }
}

class Images: ParsableObject {
    var main:String?=nil
    var others:[Int:String]?=nil

    required init(){}

    func bindProperties(binder: SnapshotParser.Binder) {
        binder.bindField(name: "main", field: &main)
        binder.bindDictionary(name: "others", dict: &others)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the library!) It's not working for me thus( And please check swiftlint to improve your syntax)

Answer (score 0):

This will parse all the snapshot children in the single object and convert it in array and you can easily parse the array of children with index

```swift
if let snap = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]{
    print(snap)

    for (index,val) in snap.enumerated(){
        print("values")
        print(val)
        print(val.value)

    }
}
```