# Trying to get data from firebase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Ok, I have a function that has to find the average of the ratings, so I store the total amount of ratings and a total sum of ratings in my firebase (which works fine). I am trying to retrieve the data, but it seems that it doesn't even enter the codeblock of the .observeSingleEvent I am using the same approach when trying to update the values, which means I get them and I add the new rating to them and then I use the code below to update the values:

```
let ratingObject = [
   "uid" : (user?.uid)! as String,
   "totalRatings" : newRating as Int,
   "amountOfRatings" : newAmountOfRating as int
   ] as [String : Any]

dbRef.setValue(ratingObject)
```

It doesn't give an error and I am just lost

I tried to do it based on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JV9Oqyle3iE

The answers given in this thread : [how parsing Firebase FDatasnapshot json data in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870041/how-parsing-firebase-fdatasnapshot-json-data-in-swift) are just crashing the app

```
private func FindAverage(uid: String) -> Int {

    var totalRatings = 0
    var amountOfRatings = 1
    let dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("ratings").child(uid)

    dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]
        totalRatings = dict?["totalRatings"] as? Int ??  0
        amountOfRatings = dict?["amountOfRatings"] as? Int ??  1

    }){ (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    return((Int)(totalRatings/amountOfRatings))
}
```

Database structure
[image]

Any tips and help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to return value out of completion handler.

Your function should be like:

```
private func findAverage(byUid uid: String, completion: @escaping (_ average: Int) -> Void) {
    // ...
    dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
            return
        }
        totalRatings = dict["totalRatings"] as? Int ?? 0
        amountOfRatings = dict["amountOfRatings"] as? Int ?? 1

        completion((Int)(totalRatings / amountOfRatings))
    })
}
```

Something like this, check Swift docs (about completion handlers etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the response! It worked wonderfully! But what worked for me was not:  `private func findAverage(byUid uid: String, completion: @escaping (_ average: Int) -> Void)` but `private func findAverage(byUid uid: String, completion: @escaping ((_ average: Int?)) -> ())`

Comment: @DomasG It's almost the same, but optional. Glad to hear, that it helped. You can also accept an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
private func FindAverage(uid: String) -> Int {
  var totalRatings = 0
  var amountOfRatings = 1
  let dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("ratings").child(uid)
  dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
     if snapshot.exists() {
        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
           return
        }
        totalRatings = dict?["totalRatings"] as? Int ??  0
        amountOfRatings = dict?["amountOfRatings"] as? Int ??  1
     }
   }){ (error) in
      print(error.localizedDescription)
   }
   return((Int)(totalRatings/amountOfRatings))
}
```